# How to use an imported string as an installation target folder in Wix,

Tags: c#, wix

After defining a property, how to set the directory name to a that property you've defined.

I defined a property here which read a value from the registry, and I assign it to the property.

```
<Property Id="REGISTRY_VALUE">
<RegistrySearch Id="RegistrySearchId" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\YourCompany\YourApp" Name="YourRegistryKey" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

I used the property to set INSTALLDIR name based on the property value

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
<Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="[REGISTRY_VALUE]">
<!-- Add your files and other components here -->
</Directory>
</Directory>
```

But INSTALLDIR Directory is still created as [REGISTRY_VALUE] not with name of REGISTRY_VALUE property. I also tried using custom action to assign the directory name to property during installation but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You use a setproperty custom action (msi type 51) scheduled prior to CostInitialize to assign INSTALLDIR [REGISTRY_VALUE].  It's important to only do this with a condition of Not Installed and Not INSTALLDIR.  This is because directories are immutable for an already installed product (major upgrade would not be considered installed yet... and this is the typical use case for what you are doing) and you want to respect anything that was passed in at the command line.